# Login with facebook in React Native

Tags: facebook, react-native, authentication, facebook-login

I am working on a project that requires a facebook login, I have tried lots of things but non of them seem to work.

This is the code I have:

```
    import FBSDK from 'react-native-fbsdk';
const {
  LoginButton,
} = FBSDK;

/** Code */

render() {
    return (
<LoginButton 
     publishPermissions={['publish_action']}
     onLoginFinished={
       (error, result) => {
         (error) {
             alert('Login failed with error: ' + result.error);
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             alert('Login was cancelled');
         } else {
             alert('Login was successful with permissions: ' 
                 + result.grantedPermissions)
         }
      }
    }
    onLogoutFinished={() => alert('User logged out')}
  />
 }
}
```

If you know how to solve this please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: The error im getting is: **Invarian Violation: Native component for "RCTFBLoginButton" does not exist** hope this works for you

Comment: just from googling, there is an open issue on their repo: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17957 . they suggest to run react-native link, gradlew clean and then run again